# Google App Engine: Encrypt Blobs Before Upload

Tags: python, google-app-engine, blobstore

I am trying to encrypt a blob before uploading it in the Google App Engine Blobstore.

Here is the handler

```
class MyUploadHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/myAfterUploadHandler')
        inFile =  self.request.POST.multi['file'].file
        outFile = StringIO.StringIO()
        encryptFile(inFile,outFile,DATAKEY)
        datagen, headers = multipart_encode({"file": outFile})
        request = urllib2.Request(upload_url, \
                              datagen, headers)
        self.response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
```

I am having problems with the last line where urllib2 tries to post the request.

here is the final parte of the long exception

```
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 270, in fetch
    allow_truncated, follow_redirects, validate_certificate)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/urlfetch.py", line 326, in make_fetch_call
    request.set_payload(payload)
  File "cpp_message.pyx", line 124, in cpp_message.SetScalarAccessors.Setter (third_party/apphosting/python/protobuf/proto1/cpp_message.cc:2229)
TypeError: <type 'instance'> has type <type 'instance'>, but expected one of: str, unicode
```

Comment: Not an answer to that specific problem but I would advise you to use the [Python Client for Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/) if possible.

Comment: Here is my gist showing how an app can send a blob to the blobstore. https://gist.github.com/voscausa/9222732

Comment: @voscausa Thank you! Do you think GCS would be better? I am really considering the Jaime advise

Comment: Yes GCS would be much better. The files API has been depricated.  Here you can see how I use GCS as a replacement: https://github.com/voscausa/appengine-gcs-blobstore-python With GCS you can still use blobstore download and upload

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you have a misunderstanding of how the blobstore upload is designed to work. Currently, it seems like you are uploading a file to the MyUploadHandler handler in your app engine, which is in  then uploading it to the blobstore at the URL you got from create_upload_url.

This is not how it is meant to work. You are supposed to return the url you get from create_upload_url **back to the client**. The client is then supposed to initiate the file upload to that url.

If you are encrypting the file, you need to do it on the client side during the last step.

Comment: I know how ti works but I need the client to be encrypted server side. That is the reason of my weird attempt. I think I am going to use the cloud storage API

Comment: so you want to send a file over the network in clear text, but encrypt it on the server side before you store it? it is a strange requirement. can you explain your use case?

Comment: I see, that makes sense. You are not giving me enough context, so not sure how I can help any more. But there should never be a need to upload to anything but the blobstore. You can use the GCS client library after the upload to encrypt. But note that if you are uploading unencrypted to the server, and then applying encryption, there is going to be some duration of time in which the file will be on the server and unencrypted. Make sure you are ok with that situation.

Comment: I am switching to GCS